# Trying to download file from database using angular 5 and asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript

I am trying to download a file that has been uploaded successfully to a database by id. Does anyone know what is needed to be done to get the correct outcome?

I have a FileUpload table that has the following columns (related to the file):

```
Id = uniqueidentifier,
Content = varbinary,
ContentType = nvarchar, e.g. application/pdf
FileName = nvarchar, e.g. filename.pdf
FileType = tinyint
```

Here is the method in the Controller.

```
/// <summary>
/// Download the file from the database by id.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
/// <returns>The file.</returns>
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetDownloadFile(Guid id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        throw new UserFriendlyException("File not found.");
    }
    var file = await _fileUploadRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(id);
    var filename = file.FileName.ToString();
    var fileBytes = file.Content;
    return File(fileBytes, file.ContentType,file.FileName);
}
```

Here is the typescript trying to call the controller but it doesn't work (I've only included relevant code):

```
constructor(
injector: Injector,
private _fileUploadsServiceProxy: FileUploadsServiceProxy,
private _notifyService: NotifyService,
private _tokenAuth: TokenAuthServiceProxy,
private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
private _fileDownloadService: FileDownloadService,
private _searchService: SearchService,
private http: Http
) {
super(injector);
}

/// <summary> 
/// Download the file from the database.
/// </summary>
///<param name="file">The file.</param>
downloadFile(file: any): void {
    if (file.fileUpload.id) {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', file.fileUpload.contentType);
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + abp.auth.getToken());

        this.http.get(`${AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl}/FileUploadComponents/DownloadFile?id= ${file.fileUpload.id}`, {
            headers: headers,
            responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
        })
            .subscribe(result => {
                saveAs(result.blob(), file.fileUpload.fileName);
                this.notify.success(`Downloaded ${file.fileUpload.fileName} successfully.`);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work". What is the result after executing the above code?

Comment: Literally nothing happens when I try to call DownloadFile in the controller. I've added a breakdon on the first curly brace but it never hits it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You C# code seems correct, but you TypeScript/Angular code will not call the `GetDownloadFile` action of you API.

The `http.get(...)` method returns an observable and the HTTP request will only be fired when you subscribe to it.

```
public downloadFile(id: number): void {
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/octetstream');
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + abp.auth.getToken());

  this.http.get(`${AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl}/FileUploadComponents/DownloadFile?id= ${id}`)
    .subscribe(result => {
      // result contains your file data.
    });
}
```

Now, you will need to save your file, you can use the [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) package.

Install the package using the following command in your project root directory (where `package.json` is located)

```
npm install file-saver --save
```

And then update your code to import and call the file-saver method to save your file.

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

public downloadFile(id: number): void {
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/octetstream');
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + abp.auth.getToken());

  this.http.get(`${AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl}/FileUploadComponents/DownloadFile?id= ${id}`).subscribe(result => {
    saveAs(result, 'fileName');
  });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I try the new code mentioned above I get the status code 204 no content.  Am I doing something wrong? 

Here is the summary:
Request URL: http://localhost:22742/FileUploadComponents/DownloadFile?id=%2030e51bad-c2e4-4a03-2abb-08d6ad838f77
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: [::1]:22742
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: You can try to add an extra parameter to your `http.get` call: `http.get('url', { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(...);` This wil indicate that you are requesting a blob type instead of real content.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked I'll updated my code above of the working solution.